# Want to remote open for zkaccess Access Controller with zkemkeeper.dll with C# Application

Tags: c#, dll, sdk

I use and install zkteco 's SDK on my pc.
I have tested to remote open with zkaccess 3.5 standalone software.It is OK.

I have to know some of my development code.
I try to remote open door with ACUnlock method by passing  machineNo and Delay time .
ACUnlock Method is return true but door does not open.
Is ACUnlock to open door ?and may need to configure or register door data or other event to fire in my development code?
I also found DisableDeviceWithTimeOut Method in SDK .It can be use to open door?

```
  if (axCZKEM.ACUnlock(iMachineNumber, iDelay)) {
                    axCZKEM.RefreshData(iMachineNumber);
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6JXL.jpg)